# How to redirect sub domain from https to http?

Tags: apache, https

I need to redirect subdomain from https to HTTP
https://jokes.domain.com  to http://jokes.domain.com
I tried using. Htaccess but failed

i tried to do this :

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.
#RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

anyone can help?
and please tell me if i need to do it from the subdomain librery .Htaccess or from main .Htaccess file
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```